# The ending zeros are not showing up for the a) fee assessed and b) the total amount due columns.

Tags: parsefloat

var val = parseFloat( t.val() );
var fee = parseFloat( ( val / 100 ) * 3 ).toFixed(2));

```
                                $( '#field-convenience-fee' ).val( fee );

                                $( '#field-total' ).val( val + fee );
```

can someone help force the field-convenience-fee and total amount due fields to display the trailing zeros? (for example: 10.00 displays a fee of .3 instead of .30 and displays a total of 10.3 instead of a total of 10.30)

Plus, I have a problem with concatenation of the fee assessed + the total amount due fields.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle for your convenience: (https://jsfiddle.net/8a2qwvsw/)

You added an extra parenthesis after `toFixed(2)`:

```
var val = parseFloat( $('#t').val() );
var fee = parseFloat( ( val / 100 ) * 3 ).toFixed(2);

$( '#field-convenience-fee' ).val( fee );

$( '#field-total' ).val( val + fee );
```